# Input-view with multiple columns

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

How would I create an input-view with a list that has two columns? I want something similar to what the date-picker looks like.

My goal is to choose from 2 separate lists of values and join them together. For example if I had `list a = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `list b = [1, 2, 3]` I would want to allow the user to choose a letter and number to create `a1` or `b3`.

Answer (score 0):

Bixby currently does not support this functionality. I would recommend that you raise a [Feature Request](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) in our community. This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.